# Vue, Vuex, & Firestore: How to display retrieved Firestore data on the frontend and make it reactive?

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuex

I am having some trouble trying to display data from Firestore.  The data is binding correctly to my store but doesn't display on the web page.  I believe my issue is with Vue's caveats on reactivity.  As I am fairly new to Vue I am unsure on how I would work around the caveats to make my data reactive. [Here is a link to a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41gNC.png) with what I am seeing on the web page, my Dashboard component where I am trying to display the data, and my index.js file for my store.

Versions of Vue, Vuex, & Vuexfire used in this project:
"vue": "^3.0.0",
"vuex": "^4.0.2",
"vuexfire": "^3.2.5"

Comment: I updated the question to add the version of Vue, Vuex, & Vuexfire since I figured out that my problem was with the incompatibility of Vuexfire not supporting Vuex 4.  Ended up being a dependency problem, not a code problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching more, and help from a user on another forum we figured out that the issue was Vuexfire doesn't support Vuex 4 yet.  I am setting up snapshots using the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) to set the state in my Vuex store.  These snapshots are populating the store and updating on the frontend.  If anyone stumbles upon this and has any questions feel free to comment and I can try and help!